# Como fazer request de outro site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, api

Olá, eu estou com dificuldades para fazer um código que tenho em mente. Seria o seguinte.

Tenho um site que fala sobre os ônibus da minha cidade e estou desenvolvendo um código em `php` que procura ônibus com ar e coloca a linha/rota que ele está.

Para procurar os ônibus vejo no site http://www.mobilibus.com/web/detalhes-linha/5w71c que é da minha cidade.

Eles fazem os requests dos onibus pelo http://www.mobilibus.com/web/refresh-vehicle-in-route no método `post`.

olhando pelo network do navegador as variáveis que vou usar são:

> routeId :"000" ////Linha/rota
>
> vehicleId:"0000" ////Prefixo do ônibus
>
> vehicleLabel:"Terminal " ////Sentido que o ônibus está indo
>
> project:"5w71c" ////indica que o projeto é da minha cidade

como faço para criar um código que procure em todas as linhas/rotas de ônibus os ônibus que eu definir? Fazendo uma varredura em todas as linhas/rotas. Por exemplo:

> Se a procura achar o veículo 1308 escrever na tabela " Veiculo 1308
>   está na linha 000"

Por favor me ajude!

Comment: Seja bem vindo, você já tentou fazer algo ? Para podermos te ajudar, você deve no minimo ter tentado fazer algum código e então vir e nos dizer qual seu problema ou dúvida. Leia o [tour] para saber como funciona o site, e acesse a [help] para obter ajuda sobre o mesmo.

Comment: Como posso puxar as variáveis pela url?

Comment: Ajudava saber que http client estas a utilizar, eu recomendava utilizar o Guzzle. Um exemplo do HTTP request também ajudava para te ajudar a definir o payload do pedido.

Comment: Oq eu quero fazer é um código que vê linha por linha procurando o ônibus que eu definir